# How can i fix "Emulator: Process finished with exit code -2147483645" on android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm working on an app that shows a list of hotels, allows you to choose one, and then shows a new screen that displays the city, state, and cost per night of stay. This is a rather simple app, and I havent even added my arrayList yet. I was only testing switching screens and my event log is filled with the text shown below. If anyone can help me, I would be so thankful, because this program is due incredibly soon (tomorrow).

Event log:

> 4:09 PM   Emulator:
>   [14900:19384:0504/160925.225:FATAL:url_request_context.cc(149)] Check
>   failed: false. Leaked 1 URLRequest(s). First URL:
>   http://wpad/wpad.dat.
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: Backtrace:
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler::qt_static_metacall
>   [0x00007FFD695AC2D5+527173]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler::qt_static_metacall
>   [0x00007FFD695BD263+596691]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler::qt_static_metacall
>   [0x00007FFD6954148B+89339]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FFD6993BCBF+3600687]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FFD6993BACC+3600188]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FFD6993BB8C+3600380]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator:
>   QtWebEngineCore::ProfileAdapterClient::downloadInterruptReasonToString
>   [0x00007FFD680C97D3+6547]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator:
>   QtWebEngineCore::ProfileAdapterClient::downloadInterruptReasonToString
>   [0x00007FFD680C9994+6996]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler::qt_static_metacall
>   [0x00007FFD695B48B5+561445]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler::qt_static_metacall
>   [0x00007FFD69535E80+42736]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler::qt_static_metacall
>   [0x00007FFD695358CC+41276]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler::qt_static_metacall
>   [0x00007FFD695862E5+371541]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler::qt_static_metacall
>   [0x00007FFD69586B42+373682]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler::qt_static_metacall
>   [0x00007FFD69565229+236185]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: QWebEngineUrlScheme::QWebEngineUrlScheme
>   [0x00007FFD690CA0CD+10280893]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler::qt_static_metacall
>   [0x00007FFD69568B1B+250763]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler::qt_static_metacall
>   [0x00007FFD69537205+47733]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFDF1A77BD4+20]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFDF29CCE51+33]
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator:
>
> 4:09 PM   Emulator: Process finished with exit code -2147483645

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is from the emulator. You can try your code in real device or in another emulator. Sometimes emulators in Android Studio have bugs and need to be reinstalled.